# concurrent modification mismatching etag value in Syncope

Tags: apache-http-server

I am trying to edit my password using syncope-console. When i enter the new passwords and click on FINISH , i get a error in a dialog box stating "concurrent modification mismatching etag value" . Help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to mismatch between the etag of the object that you are editing in the Syncope console and the etag on Syncope database. They should be aligned.
Try to clean your browser cache or simply to reload page with the list of users.
Please refer to documentation [here](https://syncope.apache.org/docs/2.1/reference-guide.html#etag-if-match-and-if-none-match)